# Mockito - MissingMethodInvocationException

Tags: android, mockito, retrofit2, rx-android

I am trying to test that an API call is scheduled on the right scheduler and observes on the main thread.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Observable.class, AndroidSchedulers.class})
public class ProductsPresenterTest {

    private  ProductsPresenter presenter;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        presenter = spy(new ProductsPresenter(mock(SoajsRxRestService.class)));
    }


    @Test
    public void testShouldScheduleApiCall(){
        Observable productsObservable = mock(Observable.class);
        CatalogSearchInput catalogSearchInput = mock(CatalogSearchInput.class);
        when(presenter.soajs.getProducts(catalogSearchInput)).thenReturn(productsObservable);

        /* error here*/ 
        when(productsObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())).thenReturn(productsObservable);
        when(productsObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())).thenReturn(productsObservable);
        presenter.loadProducts(catalogSearchInput);

        //verify if all methods in the chain are called with correct arguments
        verify(presenter.soajs).getProducts(catalogSearchInput);
        verify(productsObservable).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        verify(productsObservable).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        verify(productsObservable).subscribe(Matchers.<Subscriber<Result<Catalog<SoajsProductPreview>>>>any());
    }
}
```

The line

```
when(productsObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())).thenReturn(productsObservable);
```

throws the following exception, and **I don't understand why since productObservable is a mock**. Any idea or similar experience?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Comment: Have you tried a Matcher, i.e. when(productsObservable.subscribeOn(any(Scheduler.class))), or maybe a Captor?

Comment: Yes, I did and obtained the same error

Comment: Can you try the `doReturn().when()` syntax, sometimes it solves issues like yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due Observable::subscribeOn being a final method, which [Mockito can't mock](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito).
One possible solution is to use Powermock:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Observable.class)
public class MockTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Observable productsObservable = PowerMockito.mock(Observable.class);

        when(productsObservable.subscribeOn(null)).thenReturn(productsObservable);
        productsObservable.subscribeOn(null);
        verify(productsObservable).subscribeOn(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My error was to use Mockito.mock eventhough I used the PowerMockRunner